Django: Network graph/plot not displaying on webpage (solutions with Gravis/PyVis?)
I want to display an interactive network graph on my webpage (similar to the ones shown here), and I am using Networkx, Gravis, and Django. The image does not show up, and neither does it thow any errors. I would like suggestions or corrections to my code (given below) so that I can get the thing working...
Suggestions for using alternative packages (I already tried PyVis) are also welcome, as long as the packages are easy to work with from within a Django project/app framework.
PyVis seems good, but it needs to create a .html file to display a plot. How does that work with a user who visits my webpage? Is the .html file created in their devices, or my server?
My end goal is to make the nodes in the interactive plot clickable, so that I can get the names of the nodes the user clicks...but I guess that comes later. First I need to get the basic network graph to at least show up on the webpage.
Here are my codes:
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import gravis as gv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pyvis.network import Network



def merge(list1, list2):   
     merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]     
     return merged_list

# USING Gravis
def plot_netx_gravis(topic_string,request):
    nx_csv=pd.read_csv('NetworkXNodes/'+topic_string+'_NetworkX_Edgelist.csv', index_col=None)    
    connection_tuples=merge(nx_csv['Child'].to_list(),nx_csv['Parent'].to_list())
    G1=nx.DiGraph()
    G1.add_edges_from(connection_tuples)
    image=gv.d3(G1).to_html()
    template = 'topics4node_2.html'
    return render(request, template, {'image':image})

topics4node_2.html
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %}Gravis Graph{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h6>Here, the graph...</h6>
        {% autoescape off %}
        {% if image %}
            <image class="html">
                {{image}}
            </image>
        {% endif %}
        {% endautoescape %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

